# How To Get Object from Angularjs to Serverside Api?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I have an MVC and API WebApplication Project in my VisualStudio. On Client side I work with angulrjs. To communicate between client and server I want to use angularjs resource to sent data to my crud Api methods.

Getting the data (Car objects in an array) and changing it on client side works fine.

The problem is creating a new Object. Although the object I create seems to have the same variables and datatypes as my objects I have from server side, whenever I try to send them to the server it doesn´t work. 
My Suggestion is that the dataType is still different and the method isn´t calld because of the different parameter.

1. Is there a way to create a complex dataType in js that will be recognized as the one on serverside?
2. Are there other possibilities to create a new object on client side?
   (One idea I had was to send an empty object form server to fill it on client side, but that seems odd...)

Comment: can you try json.Stringify(yourObject)

Comment: Can you provide the code you're currently using to create the object? Also, were you able to create a server side object using a tool such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: yourUrl,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json"
        })
```

Are you sending the data cross origin?